# Normal Distribution, probability that X differs from expected value by less than 10%

Tags: probability-distributions

I have a normal approximation of binomial, $X\sim \mathcal{N}(36,4.6475)$.
I have to find the probability that the number of red blocks ($\mu = 36$) differs from its expected value by less than $10\%$.
I know how to calculate normal distribution, I just don't understand how exactly I should work with these percentages and expected value?

Heeeelp.
I tried calculating it between 32.4 and 39.6
But it should be between 32.5 and 39.5 why is that?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

To be found is $P\left[\left|X-36\right|<3.6\right]$ since $X$ differs
from its expectation by less than 10% iff $\left|X-36\right|<3.6$.

Comment: Ah thanks, that is all i had trouble visualising. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Although I do understand that logic, If I try to find the normCdf between 36-3.6 and 36+3.6 the answer i get is 0.561
This is normal approximation of binomial (90,0.4).

I need my answer to be 0.5486, which is less.
Do you have an idea of how to achieve that?

Comment: Did you substitute the right parameter?  Sometimes people work with $N\left(\mu,\sigma^{2}\right)$ but other times with $N\left(\mu,\sigma\right)$. If that's not the problem then I cannot help you.

Comment: Can you just tell me what exactly you get for this question? :)

Comment: Sorry but I can't. I have not the disposal of tables, calculators or that sort of things. In some way I even 'hate' them.

Comment: Try this one: $P\left[\left|X-36\right|<0.1\times X\right]$. Here
the difference between $X$ and its expectation is less than $10\%$
of $X$ (instead of less than $10\%$ of its expectation). If it works then let me know. In that case I will adapt my answer.